# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable when I'm using WHILE

Tags: python

> Hello,
>   I'm trying to make a simple iteration to get 1000 vectors to used them in another calculation, I >have tried many things but still I'm getting this error of "float" object is not iterable when I'm >using while.
>   Here is my script:

```
import random
count = 1000
alfa_1 = [0, 1]
alfa_2 = [0, 1]
d = [0, 1]
while count > 0:
    print count
    for i in range(count):
        alfa_1 = random.random () * (max (alfa_1) - min(alfa_1)) + min (alfa_1)
        alfa_2 = random.random () * (max(alfa_2) - min(alfa_2)) + min (alfa_2)
        d = random.random () * (max(d) - min(d)) + min(d)
        paramvect = [alfa_1, alfa_2, d]
        print paramvect
        count = count - 1
```

> Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5):

You initially assign `alfa_1` and `alfa_2` `list` values, but later assign them to `float` values.

```
# As lists
alfa_1 = [0, 1]
alfa_2 = [0, 1]
...
# As floats
alfa_1 = random.random () * (max (alfa_1) - min(alfa_1)) + min (alfa_1)
alfa_2 = random.random () * (max(alfa_2) - min(alfa_2)) + min (alfa_2)
```

Consequently, on the second iteration of the loop, you pass `max` a `float` when it expects something iterable (like a `list`).  (It's not clear what the goal is here so I can't offer a more complete solution.)